# Run html web page using npm package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am very new to package.json related files. I have designed one HTML web page. I am using 3 files HTML,CSS and js. Now I am running HTML file by directly opening it into the browser. I am suggested to do this with **package.json** file and **npm** and create a link so that others can also access this web page. Can anybody please help me with this. This is a very basic question but finding difficult to do. Can somebody help me with this?
Using **Ubuntu 18.04**, **HTML5**, **CSS3**, **bootstrap 3.4.0**

Answer (score 2):

For a long time I did use [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/)

#### Install

`npm install -g browser-sync`

#### Start it

`browser-sync start --server --files "css/*.css"`

You can find more Docs on the above link.

So if you don't have a `package.json` you can do `npm init` on the root of the project.

Then on your [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) under scripts:

```
{
  ...,
  dev: browser-sync start --server --files "css/*.css",
  share: browser-sync start --proxy "myproject.dev" --files "css/*.css"
}
```

So `dev` you can use it for local development and `share` to share with others for feedback...

```
npm run dev
npm run share
```

Comment: After running this, it opens browser and gives an error "Cannot GET /"

Comment: Do you have an `index.hmtl` in the folder you running `npm run dev`

Comment: I am using this command `browser-sync start --server "main.html" --files "main.html"`. As my file name is main.html. And as per https://www.browsersync.io/ if I have html file then I have to use server. But still not working.